# In Excel how do you a find a selection of text that exists within a list of text?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

Another excel question following some great help I got on a similar query, say i have some text which is part of a URL say:

```
example-text
```

then the output of the formula i want finds in a long list of urls whether 'example-text' occurs and then if does returns the full url from the list that was searched ? say:

```
www.lalala/example-text/lala/random.com
```

Would be great if someone could solve this for me ?

**added:**

oh i see, thanks again. yeah I dont think I explained it well enough, i'll have another stab: say i have a long list of urls i want to be able to see whether "example-text" occurs in the url's, then if so the forumla output itslef is the url that contains "example-text".. is that doable ? thanks. Edward

Answer (score 1):

Try the find [***<sup>doc</sup>***](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php) function:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2,A1,1)),"Not in the url",A1)
```

(assuming your url is in `A1` and the `example-text` in cell `A2`

Comment: thanks jmax. just tried and couldnt get it to go.. would this formula work over a list ? also how to get it to return the url that contains the correct searched fragment ?

Comment: here is an [example on GoogleDocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avv4SM5QSNYtdHlUU3E0REFMMVdjVFpQeUkwOVVZRWc&hl=en_GB) (works almost the same as in Excel)

Comment: oh i see, thanks again. yeah I dont think I explained it well enough, i'll have another stab: say i have a long list of urls i want to be able to see whether "example-text" occurs in the url's, then if so the forumla output itslef is the url that contains "example-text".. is that doable ? thanks. Edward

Comment: @Edward: you can edit you question (see the `edit` link at the bottom of your question) to explain us more what you intend to do

Comment: @Edward: i edited my answer. the best way to learn is to try to understand the formula and adapt it to your needs. If it is not clear, please ask but we'd rather teach you how to fish than give you the final fish...

Comment: Thanks greatly Jmax, yeah your right definetly wiser to point me in the right direction rather than giving me the answer cold.. I am trying to solve now.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yet, my new edited answer should fit your needs (or maybe I missed something?). Please don't hesitate to come and comment here or ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA user-defined function you can use to return the first item in a list that contains your search text.  Just enter this code in a new module in the VBA editor window (Alt+F11 to open VBA editor).

```
Public Function FIRSTWITHIN(lookfor As String, lookin As Variant) As String

Dim tmparray() As Variant
Dim firstmatch As String
firstmatch = "No matching URL found."

'Feeds lookin into temporary array.  Error Handler handles case where lookin is a range.
'This allows use of function in array formula.
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
tmparray = lookin

'Looks through array column by column for match.  Returns first match found.
For j = 1 To UBound(tmparray, 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(tmparray, 1)
        If InStr(tmparray(i, j), lookfor) > 0 Then
            firstmatch = tmparray(i, j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If firstmatch <> "No matching URL found." Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next j
FIRSTWITHIN = firstmatch
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    tmparray = lookin.Value
    Resume Next

End Function
```

You can then use the function as follows:

```
=FIRSTWITHIN("example-text",A2:A20)
```

where A2:A20 is the list of URLs you want to search through.